# BeautifulSoup Scraping Data - Specify rows? Subcategorise?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am fairly new at Python scripting and would appreciate some help.

I have been using beautifulsoup to scrub web data and I am trying to extract the spaceports in the "pages in category "spaceport" part of the wikipedia page. I manage to scrub the page however I end up extracting the top subcategories as well, I've been using the following code, could you please give me some pointers?

```
data = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Spaceports").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
splist = []
sp_df = pd.DataFrame({"Spaceport": splist})
sp_df.head()
```

Outpu

```
Spaceport

 
0
Spaceport 

1
List of rocket launch sites 

2
Alcântara Launch Center 

3
Anheung Proving Ground 

4
Baikonur Cosmodrome
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post a question, check that it is a question... In this case, you are not providing information about which one is your problem, so it is difficult to help you. What are your trying to get? Why the output is not expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Spaceports").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser').find("div", {"id": "mw-pages"})
spaceports = [f"https://en.wikipedia.org{a['href']}" for a in soup.find_all("a")[3:]]

for spaceport in spaceports:
    print(spaceport)
```

Output:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alc%C3%A2ntara_Launch_Center
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anheung_Proving_Ground
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baikonur_Cosmodrome
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barreira_do_Inferno_Launch_Center
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biak_Spaceport
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broglio_Space_Center
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnarvon,_Western_Australia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Churchill_Rocket_Research_Range
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dombarovsky_Air_Base
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guiana_Space_Centre
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammaguir
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naro_Space_Center
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey_(launch_platform)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palmachim_Airbase
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reggane
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolute_Bay
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_Lab_Launch_Complex_1
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanirajak
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satish_Dhawan_Space_Centre
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semnan_spaceport
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonmiani_(space_facility)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svobodny_Cosmodrome
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanegashima_Space_Center
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thumba_Equatorial_Rocket_Launching_Station
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilla_Satellite_Launch_Centre
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uchinoura_Space_Center
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vostochny_Cosmodrome
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoshinobu_Launch_Complex
```

EDIT:
To grab just the names of the space ports change the last line from this:

```
    print(spaceport)
```

To this:

```
    print(spaceport.rsplit("/")[-1])
```

Comment: one more follow up on this, if I wished to then just extract the names at the end of the URL i.e. Anheug_Proving_Ground and not the full URL, what code would you add?